# Error: Could not resolve "./lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, whatsapp

I'm trying to implement some integrations using the [whatsapp-web.js](https://wwebjs.dev/) lib on a website in [vitejs](https://vitejs.dev/) and react-ts.

When I only run the implementation script, the application runs normally.

However, when I implement this script on the website I am receiving the error

```
[ERROR] Could not resolve "./lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg"

    node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js:1:56:
      1 │ module.exports = process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV ? require('./lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg') : require('./lib/fluent-ffmpeg');
```

fluent-ffmpeg is a dependency of [whatsapp-web.js](https://wwebjs.dev/) that is installed.

I looked at the [issue](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/573) but was unsuccessful with the solutions presented.

Has anyone had any similar experience with implementing the whatsapp-web.js lib in vitejs?